# Aligning icons to right on the same line as other inline text - CSS

Tags: html, css, icons, inline

I am trying to align some social media icons to the right of my menu but I'm having some trouble. The icons are going all over the place! Here is my code:

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#stories">Stories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#more-reads">More Reads</a></li>
 </ul>

 <i class="fa fa-facebook"><a href="#"></a></i>
 <i class="fa fa-twitter"><a href="#"></a></i>
 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"><a href="#"></a></i>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nav{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 69px;
 }
.nav li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#4D4D4D;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}
```

As you might be able to tell I'm also trying to center the elements in the div, but I can't tell if thats working until I get it on the right side.
I have tried floating the i tag right but that is still underneath everything else.

If someone could help me that would be great :)

Comment: If you float the <i> place it before the <ul> to prevent that is still underneath. To center the div.nav set width and margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```css
.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 69px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

i {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#stories">Stories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#more-reads">More Reads</a></li>
        </ul>

        <i class="fa fa-facebook"><a href="#"></a></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"><a href="#"></a></i>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"><a href="#"></a></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```